# Does the standalone package not play well with the exam class?

Tags: incompatibility, exam, standalone

Here is a very minimal example:

```
\documentclass[class=exam]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}

    \question
    Text.

    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

It produces the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8
```

But run with `\documentclass{exam}` it works correctly.

Comment: My understanding was that by passing the option "class=exam" to standalone, it bases the standalone document on the exam class. From the standalone documentation: "Specifies the underlying class which is loaded by the standalone class."

Comment: Adding [varwidth=true] works.  It has to do with things like \textwidth being undefined.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo! It seems that [crop=false] also achieves this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `standalone` is targeted at single diagramms which are single boxes, not paragraphs. Therefore the content is processed in *restricted horizontal mode* which doesn't allow vertical content like text lines or lists. If you need to add text you need enable paragraph processing again.

This can be done by either switching from the normal `crop` mode to `preview` which handles the content in vertical mode OR by adding the `varwidth` option which wraps the content into a `varwidth` environment (from the `varwidth` package) before. This way the list is turned into a box.

This has nothing to do with the `exam` class, but by the fact, that the `questions` environment is implemented as a list or similar.