# Get cropped pdf with luatex

Tags: luatex, pdfcrop

Is there a good way to automatically crop the pdf document with luatex, in order to get the same result as using pdfcrop after luatex but in one operation and without pdfcrop ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a documentclass of `standalone` will crop the output file to the content. See the documentation for the `standalone` package on CTAN.

Comment: Yes, I already tried this class (and also preview package) but I have some compilation issues (problems like here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395475/does-the-standalone-package-not-play-well-with-the-exam-class)